# Interpolating a vector about an arc (Slerp)

Tags: trigonometry, interpolation, quaternions

In the following image, how can I solve for $k_0$? I know that $\mathbf v_1$ is a unit vector and $k_1 = \sin tω/\sin ω$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this while reading through *3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development* as well.

Took awhile to figure out, but if you make a parallelogram using $v_1$, $k_1v_1$, and $k_0v_0$:

[image: Image of parallelogram]

you can find the angle (labeled $a$ in my picture).
You can then use the law of sines to solve for triangle $k_0v_0$, $k_1v_1$, and $v_t$.

You end up with $(k_0v_0 / \sin((1-t)w)) = k_1v_1 / \sin(tw)$. Since $v_1$ is a unit vector, $v_0$ is a unit vector and $k_1 = (\sin(tw)/\sin(w))$, this simplifies to

$$k0 / \sin((1-t)w) = 1/\sin(w)$$

Multiply both sides by $\sin((1-t)w)$ and we end up with $k0 = (\sin(1-t)w) / \sin(w)$.